# Getting all occurences in a string with Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, prototype

First of all I am not an expert on JavaScript, in fact I am newbie.

I know PHP and there are functions to get all occurences of a regex pattern `preg_match()` and `preg_match_all()`.

In the internet I found many resources that shows how to get all occurences in a string. But when I do several regex matches, it looks ugly to me.

This is what I found in the internet:

```
var fileList = []
var matches
while ((matches = /<item id="(.*?)" href="(.*?)" media-type="(?:.*?)"\/>/g.exec(data)) !== null) {
    fileList.push({id: matches[1], file: matches[2]})
}

fileOrder = []
while ((matches = /<itemref idref="(.*?)"\/>/g.exec(data)) !== null) {
    fileOrder.push({id: matches[1]})
}
```

Is there a more elegant way other than this code?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Ohh. I think I did this wrong I tried to share a knowledge to newbies like me if they needed something like this. Sould I answer my question to do so?

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a forum. You should delete this unless you have a specific question about programming. You could even turn this into a question by saying "what are any problems with the approach I've used here?" although that would make it more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than here.

Comment: Yes this is not a forum but I have seen several posts that not asks questions rather showing how it's done. Are you saying that these are also  doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes they are doing it wrong. Totally wrong. "Questions" that aren't actually questions are closed, unless they have historical significance (i.e. have thousands if not millions of inbound links) and then they are locked with a note explaining that although they have been left up for that reason they are not a good fit for our Q&A format.

Comment: I would guess that you may not have seen that happening if you primarily hang out in the PHP tag, because the volume of new questions (or not questions) is too high to police effectively.

Comment: Okay. I get your point but I do not aggre with you. So I will not delete this post unless a moderator tells me so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP means it as an example to others (its not a question).

Comment: @GokhanOzturk Sharing knowledge is fine, but please try to keep it in the form of a question and an answer. [edit] your question so that it's only the question, and add the answer below as an actual answer.

Comment: Self-answering is okay. But you still need to post in a QA format.

Comment: I edited my question and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regexes on html is generally held to be a bad idea, because regexes lack sufficient power to reliably match `a^n b^n` arbitrarily nested occurrences such as balanced parens or HTML/XML open/close tags. Its also trivially easy to get data out of the DOM in JavaScript without treating it like a string, that's what the DOM is *for*. For example:

```
let mapOfIDsToFiles = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('item'))
  .reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.id] = item.href;
    return obj;
  }, {});
```

This has the added advantage of being *much* faster, simpler, and more robust. DOM access is slow, but you'll be accessing the DOM anyway to get the HTML you run your regexes over.

Modifying built-in prototypes like `String.prototype` is generally held to be a bad idea, because it can cause random breakages with third-party code that defines the same function but differently, or if the JavaScript standard gets updated to include that function but it works differently.

## UPDATE

If the data is already a string, you can easily turn it into a DOM element without affecting the page:

```
let elem = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = data;
div.querySelectorAll('item'); // gives you all the item elements
```

As long as you don't append it to the document, its just a JavaScript object in memory.

## UPDATE 2

Yes, this also works for XML but converting it to DOM is slightly more complicated:

```
// define the function differently if IE, both do the same thing
let parseXML = (typeof window.DOMParser != null && typeof window.XMLDocument != null) ?
  xml => ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml') :
  xml => {
    let xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
    return xmlDoc;
  };

let xmlDoc = parseXML(data).documentElement;

let items = Array.from(xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('item'));
```

Note that if the parse fails (i.e. your document was malformed) then you will need to check for the error document like so:

```
// check for error document
(() => {
  let firstTag = xmlDoc.firstChild.firstChild;
  if (firstTag && firstTag.tagName === 'parsererror') {
    let message = firstTag.children[1].textContent;
    throw new Error(message);
  }
})();
```

Comment: But the `data` variable is not loaded to DOM. It's from a file. If you know a way to convert the string to a seperate DOM without touching the actual DOM of the page it would be great.

Comment: Is this also work if string actually an XML document?

Comment: One last thing. I am using node (actually electron) to parse this XML. So is `DOMParser` is the right object for it?

Comment: @GokhanOzturk nope, node has none of this functionality built in. But with node there are actually arguably better solutions like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js. I used it once to write a iTunes playlist converter.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the idea of creating a method in String.

I wrote a `String.prototype` that simplyfy things for me:

```
String.prototype.getMatches = function(regex, callback) {
  var matches = []
  var match
  while ((match = regex.exec(this)) !== null) {
    if (callback)
      matches.push(callback(match))
    else
      matches.push(match)
  }

  return matches
}
```

Now I can get all matches with more elegant way. Also it's resembles `preg_match_all()` function of PHP.

```
var fileList = data.getMatches(/<item id="(.*?)" href="(.*?)" media-type="(?:.*?)"\/>/g, function(matches) {
    return {id: matches[1], file: matches[2]}
})

var fileOrder = data.getMatches(/<itemref idref="(.*?)"\/>/g, function(matches) {
    return matches[1]
})
```

I hope this helps you too.